# Is the computer language 'Erlang' related to the Chinese deity?

Tags: erlang, language-history

Erlang Shen or [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_Shen) is a Chinese deity who supposedly regulates floods, [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29) a computer language ideal for large volume applications. Is this just some kind of weird coincidence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia says it's either a reference to [Agner Krarup Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agner_Krarup_Erlang), or an abbreviation for [Ericsson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ericsson) Language.  Given that it was developed by a company
based in Sweden, it's unlikely (though not impossible) that it's secretly a reference to a Chinese god.

Comment: Just love this site. Even a silly question like this gets answered in seconds!

Comment: Historical Note: my profile says 'one day I will be able to edit other peoples posts'.  ( I might change my profile one day!)

Answer (score 3):

The wiki article you linked to says

> The name "Erlang", attributed to Bjarne Däcker, has been understood either as a reference to Danish mathematician and engineer Agner Krarup Erlang, or alternatively, as an abbreviation of "Ericsson Language".[1][3]

Comment: The mathematician Agner Krarup Erlang did important work on telephone network analysis and how to calculate network loads.